# C# - MS Word - MailMerge how to get Last Record when MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord returns -16

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge, record-count

Unable to get Last record using `MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord` or `MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount` the first variable always returns -16 and the second one returns -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

`.LastRacord` and `.RecordCount` was returning -16 and -1 because I was reading data from the CSV file. 

**Solution:**
The following code will return the last record or record count reading dataset from CSV file or text file.

```
public int GetMailMergeLastRecord()
 {
       Document doc = Globals.AddIn.ActiveDocument;      
       // for storing current record
       int currentRec = (int)doc.Mailmerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord;

       //getting the last Record
       int lastRecord = 1;
       doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = (doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord - (int)doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord) + Int32.MaxValue;
       lastRecord =  (int)doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord;

       // resetting the current record as above line of codes will change the active record to last record.
       doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = (doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord - (int)doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord) + currentRec;
       return lastRecord;
}
```

**Note**

 The above code is for word application level AddIn